# Find the conditions on a and b such that the system below has a unique solution, no solutions and infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

The system:
$x+ay=1$
$bx+y=2$

Note: I have to find the unique and infinitely many solutions
I set-up the augmented matrix but my answers didn't come from any operations:

What I got: -The system has a unique solution (x=1, y=2) if a=b=0.
-The system has no solution if a=b=1, then we will have a contradiction.
-The system has infinitely many solutions when $a ≠ 0, a ≠ 1, b ≠ 0, b ≠ 1,$ then solutions will be $ay+x=1$ and $bx+y=2$.
What am I doing wrong and is there a way I could get to this other than simply observing since the matrix already seems reduced?

Comment: What about $a=3$ and $b \neq \frac 1  3$? Do you get a unique solution or infinitely many solutions?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This yields a unique solution (which contradicts the answer I put first), as I said I didn't know how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your system as $Au=v$, where $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & a \\ b & 1\end{bmatrix}$, $u=\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$ and $v=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$.

**Case 1: Unique solution**

It is known that if $A$ is invertible, then the system has **unique** solution. This is because we can write $$u=A^{-1}v.$$ Therefore, we look for a condition that $A$ is invertible. Such condition is that $\det{A} \neq 0$. In your case: $$1\cdot1-a\cdot b \neq 0.$$

**Case 2: Multiple solutions**

This happens when the two equations describe the same situation. Each of $x+ay=1$ and $bx+y=2$ describe two lines in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane. The solution is given by the points $(x,y)$ which describe the intersection of the two lines. If we seek the case where we have infinite solution points $(x,y)$, we mean that the two lines are identical. This happens if the equations are the same. As $x+ay=1$ is equivalent to $2x+2ay=2$ (observe how the right-hand side is the same for both equations now), we can deduce that $b=2$ and $a=\dfrac{1}{2}$ yield the same equation. In conseqence, we have infinitely-many solutions.

**Case 3: No solutions**

This part does not need to be treated as you already determined the values for $a,b$ which yield solutions (unique or infinitely many). So, to have no solutions, you require
$$ab = 1\text{ and } b\neq2.$$

Observe how the condition above excludes first unique solution and then infinite case.

Hope it helps and clarifies the process of finding $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time in writing this answer. Is there any other way to get this as we are still not allowed to used things such as the determinant in the exam as we didn't get into them in the course so this solution won't be very helpful for my review (we usually do reduced row echelon form in such a case but this seemed already reduced to me)

Comment: To get RRE form, you need to have instead of b the value 0 in the second row. This could be obtained by multiplying the first row by b and then subtracting it from the second equation (to get rid of b). In this process, you need to be sure that the second term from the second row (namely 1) does not end up as 0. This implies ab different than 1, i.e. the same equation for unique case.

Comment: To get infinitely-many cases, you need to repeat the procedure above, but ensure you get only 0s on the second row: now you do want to get ab=1. So you will end up with the second equation being 0x+0y=2-b. Now, if b=2, you get infinitely many equations as your system is actually just one equation which describes a line with infinitely many points OR a system which has an equation 0x+0y=(something different than 0) which is impossible -> no solutions. Hope it helps in this way! :)

Comment: I think you meant $2x+2a\color{red}y=2$

Answer (score 0):

Solution without using linear algebra:

Multiply the first equation by $b$ and subtract from the second equation. You get $(1-ab)y=2-b$. If $ab=1$ this implies $ b=2$ so there is no solution when  $ab =1$ but $b \neq 2$.

If $ab \neq 1$ the we get $y=\frac {2-b} {1-ab}$ and $x=1-ay=1-a\frac {2-b} {1-ab}$ so there is a inique solution in this case.

If $ab=1$ and $b=2$ so that $a=\frac 1  2$,  I leave it to you to verify that there are infinitely many solutions. [Hint: if the first equation is satisfied then the second one is automatically satisfied].

Comment: What would the solution in the unique and infinitely many cases? Also is there any other way to solve this? As I am currently taking the course and we still didn't get into determinants and linear dependence (still solving the systems by getting reduced row echelon form)